# What market sets the price for ethereum?

Tags: price, markets

What specific markets set the "price" for Ethereum.  I'm assuming it's some type of open market model, but can't find any information on the standard used?  For instance, Coinbase displays a price when purchasing; where is this derived from?

Subsequently, what drives the (sometimes drastic) intraday price changes?  Supply can't possibly change that much in a short period of time.  Is it just "public sentiment" of a few of the more active traders?

Answer (score 1):

Supply and demand. Poloniex, Kraken, many regional exchanges much like Bitcoin. Many of the same players. There seem to be as many ways to explain price moves as traders involved.

Comment: Maybe a more relevant question then.  Do you know who sets the price for Coinbase purchases? I don't believe they have an exchange model, so they must be basing their price off someone else's exchange.

Comment: Something like this: https://support.gdax.com/customer/portal/articles/2429575